# Check multiple columns for multiple values and return a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a list of strings and my dataframe has several columns that i need to search (each of type object).

I need to return all rows where any of the selected columns have any of the string items within them, or is part of the string.

How do i check if 4 columns in my dataframe has any one of the items in the list of strings? The string inside the column may have part of the string provided in the list object, but probably wont have it all.

Ive tried 'list' both as a tuple and as a python list:

```
list = ("25110", "25910", "25990", "30110", "33110", "43999")

new_df = df.loc[(df['column1'].isin(list)) 
    | (df['column2'].isin(list)) 
    | (df['column3'].isin(list)) 
    | (df['column4'].isin(list))]
```

When i run `new_df.shape`, i get (0, 12).

Im new to pandas, got a mountain of analysis to do for an intense uni project, and cant get this to work. Do i need to convert each column to be a string datatype first? (ive actually already tried THAT as well, but each datatype is still stubbornly an 'object').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
lst = ["25110", "25910", "25990", "30110", "33110", "43999"]
cols=['column1','column2','column3','column4']
```

Finally:

```
m=df[cols].astype(str).agg(lambda x:x.str.contains('|'.join(lst)),1).any(1)
#you can also use apply() in place of agg()
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
```

Comment: @tommytucker7182 so?actually it is filtering out the result but you can create a new column of True/False according to your condition if you don't want to filter out result

Comment: If i try to create a new dataframe from the output the output is always (0,12). If i DONT try to create a new dataframe and run code as is, when i call .shape, the dataframe remains the same size and doesnt appear to have been filtered. Thanks for answering by the way.

Comment: @tommytucker7182 check the dtypes of columns? are they string and are they contains exact values  that are in your lst variable?

Comment: I tried to run df['column1'] = df['column1'].astype(str) on all the columns i need to be strings, but it doesnt work...

Comment: @tommytucker7182 try `df[cols]=df[cols].astype(str)` after that `df.loc[df[cols].isin(lst).any(1)]`

Comment: The dataframe doesnt reduce in size using those commands ran sequentially. .shape returns to be the full size of the dataframe. The column isnt type string either, and even if it was, only a part of the string would have the lst item shown. i.e. the column data could actually be "25990 - foo"

Comment: @tommytucker7182 updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: I basically cant tell if this works or not. the original dataset is millions of rows, and this creates so much memory pressure i dont get any output, becuase the processing takes so long. Ive had to resort to just working with one column of data instead. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @tommytucker7182 yup it is a little slower for millions of rows but you can also do in 4 different steps...that will be painful by writing up 4 lines but I think That will be fast than this