# Rows of Pandas DataFrame that contain all values of a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like so:

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
1  A   B   C   E
2  C   D   E   F
3  A   C   A   B
4  A   A   B   G
5  B   nan C   E
```

And a list:

```
filt = [A, B, C]
```

What I need is a filter that keeps only the rows that have *all* the values from `filt`, in any order or position. So output here would be:

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
1  A   B   C   E
3  A   C   A   B
```

I've looked at previous questions like [Check multiple columns for multiple values and return a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68350396/7662085). In that case, however, the OP is only partially matching. In my case, all values must be present, in any order, for the row to be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### One solution

Use:

```
fs_filt = frozenset(filt)
mask = df.apply(frozenset, axis=1) >= fs_filt
res = df[mask]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4
0  A  B  C  E
2  A  C  A  B
```

The idea is to convert each row to a [`fronzenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) and then verify if a fronzenset of `filt` is a subset (`>=`) of the elements of the row.

Comment: Looks good! I figured out in the meantime that this would also work: `mask = df.apply(frozenset, axis=1) >= frozenset(filt)`. It seems the same, just using the syntactic sugar for `set.issubset`.